# How to configure the encoder input buffer size created by MediaCodec?

Tags: android, encode, android-mediacodec

I'm working to decode a video file and then encode to a smaller size/bit rate video file. I have finished the process of decoding and getting the raw video output buffer,but when I queue the raw output buffer to the input buffer of the encoder, it throws an overflow exception. As the capacity of the input buffer is too small to hold the raw output buffer.

I find that if I configure the width and height of the output format of the encoder bigger, the capacity of both the input and output buffer of the encoder will be bigger too.And they are very near in values.And when I configure the width and height as the orignal video size,the input buffer is big enough to hold the raw output buffer of the decoder, and I get the output video file.But I want to get a smaller size and smaller bit size video.

The key code is as belows.

```
MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec("video/avc");

MediaFormat outformat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);

int colorfmt = selectColorFormat(codecInfo, "video/avc");

outformat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorfmt);//2141391876);    

outformat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 178*1024*8);

outformat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 24);

outformat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);

//outformat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 3400000);;

MediaCodec encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");

encoder.configure(outformat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

encoder.start();
```

Extract video and decode

```
   int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);

   if (inIndex >= 0) {

   ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];

   int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);

   if (sampleSize < 0) {

       decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

       isEOS = true;

   } else {

       decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);

    extractor.advance();

   }
```

}

Encode and mux to mp4 file

```
int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);

switch (outIndex) {

case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:

    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");

    outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();

    break;

case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:

    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());

    MediaFormat infmt = decoder.getOutputFormat();

    break;

case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:

    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");

    break;

default:

    ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
    buffer.position(info.offset);
    buffer.limit(info.offset + info.size);
    int encInputIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
    if (encInputIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer encBuffer = encInputBuf[encInputIndex];
        encBuffer.clear();
        encBuffer.put(buffer);
        encoder.queueInputBuffer(encInputIndex, 0, info.size, info.presentationTimeUs,0);
    }



ByteBuffer[] encOutputBuf = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
   int trackindex = 0;
   while(true) {
       MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
       int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000);
       if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
          // no output available yet
          break;                
       } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
          // not expected for an encoder
          encOutputBuf = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
       } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
          MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();
          // now that we have the Magic Goodies, start the muxer
          trackindex = muxer.addTrack(newFormat);
          muxer.start();
     } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
          // let's ignore it
     } else {
          ByteBuffer buf = encOutputBuf[encoderStatus];
          muxer.writeSampleData(trackindex, buf, bufferInfo);
          encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
     }
}
```

@fadden Wish to discuss with you and get your help.Thanks!

Comment: What you want will be slow and a bit painful if you move the data through YUV ByteBuffers.  If you handle frames through a Surface it gets a bit easier, because you can send the decoded frame to a SurfaceTexture and then use the GLES scaler to resize it.  http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest shows all the pieces but doesn't attempt to re-scale.  Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) has video recording activities that accept camera input and re-scale it on the way to the encoder.

Comment: Thanks,fadden.Very helpful information.Is it doable for all input video files and devices to decode frames and send to GLES to resize it?And,what's the difference between ByteBuffer and Surface format?In fact, I really have little idea about color format. More to ask, the MediaCodec and other media classes only work after api level 16, if I want to resize video files on devices before android 4.1,what can I do?Is it practicable to do that using OpenMax?

Comment: Hi fadden, Is it not able to change the frame rate by setting the KEY_FRAME_RATE value of encoder?When we queue input buffer of encoder with presentationtime, it decides the output frame rate, am I right?In that case, what's the effect of setting the KEY_FRAME_RATE?

Comment: The combination of FRAME_RATE and I_FRAME_INTERVAL determines the GOP size.  The presentation time stamps determine the frame rate, which can be variable.  Before MediaCodec appeared in API 16, there is no API for doing what you want.  Surfaces can be shared between media codecs and GLES, but can't generally be accessed directly by an app, which makes it easier for the drivers to do things efficiently.

Comment: Thanks,fadden.Can I use MediaCodec to decode and encode and use muxer of ffmpeg to write output file? Is the buffer interface compatible with the ffmpeg frame interface?

Comment: I haven't worked with ffmpeg, so I don't know.  MediaCodec encoders output NAL units, so it'll probably work, but I don't know if there are any odd quirks.  MediaMuxer is API 18+, so for older devices you'll have to make something like that work.  It may even be possible to install a command-line version of ffmpeg and just exec it to convert the raw H.264 file to .mp4.

Comment: Very helpful!Does the raw H.264 file contain audio track?

Comment: No, it's video only.  It has no presentation timestamps either, though for fixed-rate video that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi fadden,I have read the CameraCaptureActivity code and find it difficult to assure how it rescale the size of the camera frame.I only find the output width and hight in the configuring code of the encoder,but have no idea of how the GLES rescales the preview size to output size.What's more,is the GLES rescaling using HW method?Is it faster than SW scaling such as sw_scale in ffmpeg?

Comment: And what's the output color format of decoder?Is it certain for all devices?Because I find that there are two format of YUV,one is planner,one is packed, and the sw_scale of ffmpeg interface requires uint8* [] for input and output,if I use it,how can I convert byte[] from decoder to uint8* [] ? Sorry，I really have many questions. Many thanks for you!

Comment: The size at which frames are recorded for CameraCaptureActivity is determined by the arguments to `TextureMovieEncoder.EncoderConfig()`.  Scaling with a bilinear filter is one in hardware when the frame is rendered to the Surface that is fed into the encoder.  MediaCodec decoder output format doesn't matter if you output to a Surface; if you output to ByteBuffer it varies between devices (and may be proprietary -- see e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q5).

Comment: Hi fadden,I know the encode output format is determined by TextureMovieEncoder.EncoderConfig().But I've no idea if the GLES has matter with rescaling in the CameraCaptureActivity.Do you mean that using a Surface between MediaCodec decoder(for output) and encoder(for input) and configuring the output size of the encoder will solve the rescaling problem?

Comment: `TextureMovieEncoder#handleFrameAvailable()` uses a `FullFrameRect` to render each frame at the full size of the encoder's input surface.  That's where the scaling happens.

Comment: Thanks,fadden.Then,what's the original size of the frame?And is "the full size of the encoder's input surface" just the size configured by TextureMovieEncode.EncoderConfig?I find it really very difficult for me to extract the scaling function from the whole code to use.I also read the ExtractMpegFramesTest code and find it extract the video frame to custom width*hight png picture.It uses surface and EGL too.Can I take it for my work?(I just want to decode video and rescale it and then encode it in small bitrate.But it's really difficult for me to find a entire solution.)

Comment: The original size of the frame for "show + capture camera" is whatever the Camera is configured for.  So if the camera and output size have a different aspect ratio -- which, in this case, they usually do -- the movie will appear squashed.  (This is noted in the README.)  All of the code in Grafika is licensed under Apache 2.0 (the same license AOSP uses).

Comment: Do you mean the original size of the frame is determined by the Camera preview size?And will it be doable by replacing Camera PreviewFrame with decoder's output in the sample?But the sample has a GLSurfaceView and can use it as a SurfaceTexture,and in my situation I don't have a SurfaceView to show.

Comment: You can replace the camera output with video decoder output.  The Surface size will be set by the video decoder, which will use the size of the video being decoded.  The GLSurfaceView doesn't matter; the point of the activity is to show that you can put the camera preview on screen *and* record it by rendering the frame twice.  Other activities that encode video, such as "continuous capture", are a bit simpler because they don't have to jump through hoops to make GLSurfaceView work.

Comment: Excuse me,fadden.But how can I create a surface without SurfaceView to receive the decoder output?And should I use the same surface to do encoder configuring?Because I find the MediaCodec only supply CreateInputSurface function after API 18.This problem really has taken me a lot of time,also very sorry to bother you again and again.But I still have no idea how to rescale and encode a video using MediaCodec.I will very appreciate it if you can supply a detailed sample or the main steps to resolve the problem.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry,fadden,I didn't read the DecodeEditEncodeTest code carefully before.Now I find it requires API 18,such as MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface and createInputSurface.Then if I want to build my app targetting API 16,can I decode and encode through Surface and use GLES to rescale it?And where is the definition of InputSurface and OutputSurface in the DecodeEditEncodeTest sample?

Comment: Before API 18 it's difficult to work with MediaCodec (http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q9).  Surface input is not supported, so you can't use GLES to scale.  DecodeEditEncodeTest is part of CTS; if you remove "DecodeEditEncodeTest.java" from the source file URL you will see the full directory of files.

Comment: Hi fadden, thanks for your answer.I teste decoding video and encoding it on the original size and just configuring the bitrate smaller.I get the raw h264 file but when I play it on pc I find that there is one green line on the top of the video.Do you know what the perhaps reason is?

Answer (score 2):

Decoder in MediaCodec is not able to make resizing automatically, it always output frames in real sizes.
Encoder also encodes frames and uses real sizes as input and is not able to make resizing internally. So if you want to put frame to encoder that has sizes not equal to decoded frame you need to make resizing.

Also you can check INDE Media Pack: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde/media-pack, it has MediaComposer class, that lets you easily make video resizing

Comment: Hi,Marlon.Thanks for your answer.Then, do you know how to resize the raw video buffer(gennerally one frame)? And Is the INDE Media Pack can only be used on devices with intel cpu architechture?

Comment: Hi Frank, INDE Media Pack supports both Intel and ARM, but the requirement is 4.3+ because in lower Android version MediaCodec is bit unstable due devices fragmentatoin and fadden confirms it. Regarding resizing there could be 2 aproaches: on java level - slow and using NDK - faster, also there are different algorithms - complexity and quality trade-off, so you need to understand the requirements of your app first

Comment: Also there are color formats in which decoder outputs frame and encoder recieves what also adds extra logic to resize function. For NV12 case you can look at this C-code as a reference with couple of methods: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/691062/Resizing-NV-image-using-Nearest-Neighbor-Interpo, but the story is that some devices could work in other than nv12 color formats and you have to add the same logic for other color formats

Comment: It sounds so complex!It seems that the android api supports media decoding and encoding very limitedly.I will firstly use the MediaCodec to solve the problem, and will have a look at the INDE Media Pack when I have time.Thanks for you,Marlon.